# Call java function from javascript proxy in Jenkins plugin

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am working on a Jenkins plugin where I've designed my own custom view using Jelly and now I want to call a Java function `doFoo` on the `onClick` event of a button.

I'm trying to follow the instructions found in the [Ajax with Javascript Proxy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AJAX+with+JavaScript+proxy) wiki page like so:

***src/java/com/acme/Foo.java***

```
@JavaScriptMethod
public void doFoo(){
    //Do some foo stuff.
}
```

***src/resources/com/acme/Foo/main.jelly***

```
<button onclick="callFoo()">Click me</button>

<script>
    var foo = <st:bind value="${section}"/>
    function fallFoo() {
        foo.doFoo(function(t) {})
    }
</script>
```

However, when I click on the button I get the following error:

```
hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter doFilter
WARNING: No valid crumb was included in request for /jenkins/$stapler/bound/37592385-13a3-46a8-a03d-07bb25b6564e/doFoo. Returning 403.
```

I know the overall wiring is correct because it works fine when I disable CSRF protection by unchecking the box labeled *"Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits"* at `Manage Jenkins>Configure Global Security>Authorization`.

How can I pass a crumb to the Ajax proxy request?

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: Jan 24, 2018 6:48:04 PM hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter doFilter
WARNING: No valid crumb was included in request for /jenkins/$stapler/bound/37592385-13a3-46a8-a03d-07bb25b6564e/doDisable. Returning 403.

Comment: I solved the problem. Let me know if anyone interested.

Comment: @MukeshSingal how did you solve this issue?